# What's the easiest way to do negation in triggers?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I want to do something like

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Something}" ValueIsNot="{x:Null}">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use a Converter.  See this [blog post](http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2009/03/wpf-data-binding-datatriggers.html) for a sample for converting a result into a boolean.

```
<DataTrigger
    Binding="{Binding Path=x, Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullConverter}}"
    Value="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go with triggers, you could write your own or leverage [existing ones](http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com). If you're doing MVVM, just bind the view to a property on your VM that does the logic for you.

Comment: Do you write that value converter library? Can I contribute some?